# Unity | Animations with better performance

Tags: unity-game-engine

So i have low poly tree which don't actually need good shader for `wind animation`.

I'm thinking about creating an animations and use it for this `wind` effect, but i'm not sure about performance.

Do animations have high impact on performance? I could have 50+ trees on screen at same time.

And what would you choose for this situation? Shaders or simple animations?

Thank you

Comment: What about profiling your code for a first ?

Comment: Is there should be any code? I'm taking about impact on performance, i don't have any code problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally yes, the impact on performance of real model transformations is most likely higher then a shader solution would be. What the impact in your particular case will be (as in whether you will notice it at all) can unfortunately not really be predicted. You'll have to implement your idea and test it. Unity's built in profiler can be of help.